# Non-const copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, copy-constructor, observers

I'm doing copy on write optimization for object (i.e. when calling a copy-constructor just save pointer to an object and really copy it only if we need to change our object, or if object we are pointing to going to change).

Before changing our object we need to notify others about it, so they can perform real coping. For this action I decided to use observer pattern:

```
struct subject {
    void register_observer(const event& e, observer& obs);
    void notify(const event& e) const;

private:
    std::map<event, std::vector<observer*> > _observers;
};
```

and for observers:

```
struct observer {
    virtual void onEvent(event e);
};
```

then, our object inherits both of them. The problem is, that in copy-constructor, we need to call register_observer, which is non-const method, when we get const argument:

```
my_class::my_class(my_class const &other) {
    if (other._copy != NULL) this->_copy = &other;
    else {
        this->_copy = other._copy;
        this->_copy->register_observer(event::CHANGED, *this);
    }
}
```

One possible solution I've discovered is to use `mutable`, but I think it doesn't fit there, because object is logically changed.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Object is not logically changed. From the user point of view, nothing has changed in the object.

Comment: To reformulate what @Ninetainedo said, `mutable` is the right choice.

Comment: Why don't you make the copy constructor take a non-const reference then?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, btw I don't make the copy constructor take non-const reference because in that case I would have no ability to use it with temporary objects.

Comment: @Alexandr: You may still add a constructor that take r-value reference for temporary. But mutable seems the right choice.

Comment: 'Before changing our object we need to notify others about it, so they can perform real coping' seems the wrong way round - if you have ten things referencing the same original, and the original changes, you make ten copies. Normally copy on write means the object making the change makes the copy, the data itself is immutable, and none of the rest of your question is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you probably should use the `mutable` keyword.

Your object would still remain logically const because, from the user point of view, nothing has changed.